# Python - strings and integers in Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I want to create an array with 3 columns. The first one a string, the other two integers used for calculations. Then more rows will be added through the append function (below).

The problem is that all columns seem to be coded as strings rather than just the first one. How do I get the correct data type for the numbers?

```
a = np.array([["String",1,2]])
a = np.append(a, [["another string", 3, 4]],axis = 0)
```

Comment: `numpy` arrays are suppose to be *homogeneous*. You could use `object` dtype, but at that point, you might as well use a normal Python list. The other option is to use a structured array, or perhaps a `pandas` DataFrame.

Comment: Also, if you plan on adding a bunch of rows using `.append`, you almost *certainly* shouldn't be using a `numpy` array. Just use a Python list.

Comment: Use list first and then convert to np.array

Comment: @Mr_U4913 better yet, **stick with the list** .

Answer (score 9):

To have such a mixed datatype data, we could use `object` as dtype before appending or stacking -

```
a = np.array([["String",1,2]], dtype=object)
b = [["another string", 3, 4]]
a = np.vstack((a,np.asarray(b,object)))
```

Sample run -

```
In [40]: a = np.array([["String",1,2]], dtype=object)

In [41]: b = [["another string", 3, 4]]

In [42]: np.vstack((a,np.asarray(b,object)))
Out[42]: 
array([['String', 1, 2],
       ['another string', 3, 4]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

When collecting values iteratively, it is usually best to collect them in a list, and make the array afterwards:

For example, making a list with your data:

```
In [371]: alist = [("String", 1, 2)]
In [372]: alist.append(("another string", 3, 4))
In [373]: alist
Out[373]: [('String', 1, 2), ('another string', 3, 4)]
```

For many purposes that list is quite useful, `alist[0]`, or `[i[0] for i in alist]`.

To make a list, one option is a structured array.  Because I collected values as a list of tuples I can do:

```
In [374]: np.array(alist, dtype='U20,int,int')
Out[374]: 
array([('String', 1, 2), ('another string', 3, 4)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U20'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
In [375]: _['f1']
Out[375]: array([1, 3])
```

We access `fields` of such an array by field name.  The array itself is 1d, (2,).

If instead we make an `object` dtype array:

```
In [376]: np.array(alist, dtype=object)
Out[376]: 
array([['String', 1, 2],
       ['another string', 3, 4]], dtype=object)
In [377]: _.shape
Out[377]: (2, 3)
In [378]: __[:,1]
Out[378]: array([1, 3], dtype=object)
```

With this we can access rows and columns.  But beware that we don't get the fast numpy calculation benefits with a object array, especially one with mixed types.